# O-Notation: How to put the function in order.

Tags: asymptotics

I am new here, so I am sorry for any mistake that I'll probably make. I have an exercise to solve, but I didn't really understand how this really works.

I am given the functions $2^n$, $n^{0.01}$, $\log n$, $\log(n^3)$, $n \log n$, $n^n$, $1$, $\log \log n$, $\sqrt{n}$, $\frac{1}{n}$, $n!$, $\log(n^{\log n})$, $8^n$ and $n^8$. And the question that they made to me is:

> Sort the above functions in asymptotically ascending direction.

I don't want the solution, but a good explanation so that I can understand how to solve it.

Is there any video of explaining in plain English how I can sort the functions?

Comment: Here are some other questions similar to yours which may give you some ideas: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39497/5531 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/863216/5531 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/285954/5531 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/778297/5531 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/955186/5531 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/447803/5531

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations!  You have just won the lottery!  You will receive cash every week for the rest of your life, on one of two schedules:

1. \$1,000 today, \$1,002 next week, \$1,004 the week after that, and so on, \$1006, \$1008, \$1010… OR
2. \$0.05 today, \$0.10 next week, \$0.20 the week after that, and so on, \$0.40, \$0.80, \$1.60…

The first one gets you more money right away, but if you can wait a few months for your money, schedule 2  is  much better, because after a few months the schedule 2 payments reach \$1638.40, and after that they are always larger than the schedule 1 payments.

In this case, we say that the second schedule is *asymptotically greater* than the first schedule.  This means that **if you wait long enough, the payments of the second schedule will always be greater than the payments of the first schedule**.

The formula for the payments is that in the $n$th week, the first schedule pays $2n+998$ dollars, while the second schedule pays $\frac{2^n}{40}$ dollars.  The function $\frac{2^n}{40}$ is *asymptotically greater* than the function $2n+998$, because  $\frac{2^n}{40}$  is always greater than $2n+998$, not right away, but when $n$ is large enough.

Your job is to look at those 11 functions and put them in order according to which ones are asmyptotically greatest.  For example, do you prefer a lottery prize that pays \$1 every week, or a prize that pays \$$n!$ every week?  Obviously the second one, because after a couple of weeks its prizes are always greater than \$1.  So the function $n!$ is asymptotically greater than the function $1$.  Do you prefer a lottery prize of $8^n$ dollars in week $n$, or $n!$ dollars in week $n$?  Well, the $8^n$ prize is 8 times bigger every week than the previous week, but after week $8$, the $n!$ prize is *more* than 8 times bigger than the previous week, so if you wait long enough it must catch up to the $8^n$ prize and exceed it.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic facts that will help you: $(\log n)^c = O(n^d)$ for any $c,d > 0$. You can prove this with basic calculus. Also $n^d = O(c^n)$ for any $d > 0$ and $c > 1$ (also can be shown with calculus).

Answer (score 0):

We say that $f\in O\left(g\right)$ (as $n\rightarrow \infty$) if there exists $C>0$ and $N$
sufficiently large s.t. $\left|f\left(n\right)\right|\leq C\left|g\left(n\right)\right|$
for all $n\geq N$. For example, $\log n\leq\log n^{3}$ for all $n\geq1$,
and hence $\log n\in O\left(\log n^{3}\right)$. The assignment asks you to order
all of these functions $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$, ..., $f_{n}$ so that
$$
f_{k}\in O\left(f_{k+1}\right).
$$
For example,
$$
n,n^{2},n^{3},n^{4},...
$$
would be an ordering of the functions $\left\{ f_{k}=n^{k}\right\} $.